# how to combine jar with SQLite(executeQuery)

Tags: sqlite, user-interface, jar

I a using SQLite to hold my data and created an object for that. I also made GUI and have my object in there. But after I export my program out as a .jar file and execute it, nothing showed up.
I have narrowed down to the point where Frame will show up if I comment out where within the data object the line with "executeQuery()" function
ex.
  rs = stmt.executeQuery( "SELECT * FROM ChapSevenA;" );

does anyone know why this is happening? why nothing would showed up in jar file?

sorry for my poor English, I hope I explained my question well.

and thanks for help!

---

Edited*
When I run it on command line it showed "java.sql.SQLEception: [SQLITE_ERROR] SQL error or missing database (no such table: ChapSevenA)"

Answer (score 0):

You need to include the SQLite library files as dependencies in your Project.  You also need to include the JDBC driver, usually provided as a series of Java classes included in a JAR file as a dependency.  SQLite is not a native Java application.  It is written in C, so you'll need to use a JDBC driver that can bridge your Java application to the SQLite library files.

You'll need to edit the Project Properties for your application and add the JDBC driver as a JAR file to be included in your project.  On Netbeans, you should create a "lib" directory within your project directory tree and put the JDBC driver JAR file there.  A similar procedure can be followed for the other IDE's which you may be using.

The SQLite library files will also need to be distributed with your project so that your application can find them.  Again, place them somewhere in your project directory tree.  This enables you to use relative paths to specify file locations.  You'll have to be able to inform your JDBC driver where to locate the SQLite library files.

Comment: I am not sure if this is the right one, but I do have splite-jdbc-3.72.jar added to the library.

Comment: The project runs perfectly fine in IDE, but not when I export it as a JAR file